# How to set vertical the ouput in python?

Tags: python, output, file-writing

I would like to create an output in `.txt format in python. The problem is that the results are showing horizontally.

How can I set my values vertically?

for example my output has the format:

```
[6.48421466 4.28001787 6.76134729 5.45509747 7.68957008 3.25036695
 5.26088052 4.45128821 3.99247354 4.04626299 3.19329872 5.21477152
 5.75235725 5.4032342  4.75781543 4.86203242 4.94567754 6.2735008
 3.90191443 3.34211125 4.80198239 5.39782033 4.65575587 4.09630464
 4.68439523 4.24076152 2.70145788 3.18283344 2.67654271 6.71627663
 3.99750959 4.55231039 6.57358438 4.59699555 3.37902555 4.60574622
 5.7602282  5.34084772 4.2033163  4.41813674 5.83988272 4.56814295
 4.22884378 3.75609531 4.54537646 4.82880385 4.4317394  4.69930332
 5.46046878 3.38346653 4.02209524 4.73886735 4.91038119 3.83070474
 3.46198489 4.89056201 3.45052842 3.60843658 5.38378215 5.82383583
 3.37329096 3.72459568 5.42039616 5.4329635  5.16597499 3.61643261
 5.51898447 4.75482025 4.43989681 4.71631944 5.04887236 4.16837725]
```

I have tried:

```py
with open('outputdata.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as fout:
     fout.writelines(str(A))
```

and

```py
with open('outputdata.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as fout:
     fout.write(str(A)+'\n')
```

But it is no use. My results are showing horizontally, and not vertically (with a column format I mean)

Comment: You're outputting the string representation of a list. If you want each entry in the list output on a separate line (and no `[` brackets `]`) you can iterate over each item in the list and write it.

Comment: for the second suggetsion command error shows:TypeError: write() argument must be str, not numpy.float64    .   As for your first suggestion, I do not understand what to do... Could you explain me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to a file will always be horizontally unless you manually write each value in a different line.
I suggest you use this simple foreach loop:

```
with open('outputdata.txt','w') as fout:
    foreach item in A:
        fout.write(str(item) + "\n")
```

Of course, you can add "[" at the beginning and "]" at the end if necessary.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is your data:

```
a = [6.48421466, 4.28001787, 6.76134729, 5.45509747, 7.68957008, 3.25036695, 5.26088052, 4.45128821, 3.99247354, 4.04626299, 3.19329872, 5.21477152, 5.75235725, 5.4032342, 4.75781543, 4.86203242, 4.94567754, 6.2735008, 3.90191443, 3.34211125, 4.80198239, 5.39782033, 4.65575587, 4.09630464, 4.68439523, 4.24076152, 2.70145788, 3.18283344, 2.67654271, 6.71627663, 3.99750959, 4.55231039, 6.57358438, 4.59699555, 3.37902555, 4.60574622, 5.7602282, 5.34084772, 4.2033163, 4.41813674, 5.83988272, 4.56814295, 4.22884378, 3.75609531, 4.54537646, 4.82880385, 4.4317394, 4.69930332, 5.46046878, 3.38346653, 4.02209524, 4.73886735, 4.91038119, 3.83070474, 3.46198489, 4.89056201, 3.45052842, 3.60843658, 5.38378215, 5.82383583, 3.37329096, 3.72459568, 5.42039616, 5.4329635, 5.16597499, 3.61643261, 5.51898447, 4.75482025, 4.43989681, 4.71631944, 5.04887236, 4.16837725]
```

You can use:

```py
with open('outputdata.txt', 'w',) as f:
    f.writelines([str(x) + '\n' for x in a])
```

which results in

```
6.48421466
4.28001787
6.76134729
5.45509747
7.68957008
3.25036695
5.26088052
4.45128821
3.99247354
[...]
```